# MySQL Workbench crashing while connecting via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, mysql-workbench, virtualbox

I have the latest version of MySQL Workbench. I have MySQL in a virtual Ubuntu machine and am trying to connect via SSH.

MySQL Workbench keeps crashing without showing any warning or error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue by increasing the ssh connect timeout and ssh command retry count. This issue occurs with mysql version lower then 5.6, Above version 5.6 it works perfectly.
[image: prefrences of workbench]

Answer (score 12):

I was also facing the same issue in ubuntu, later found out that there was a permission of ssh-keys missing in the ubuntu software app.
See the last permission in the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: My crashing version already had the ssh-keys permissions

Comment: This fixed it for me. I turned on "ssh-keys..." and "read, add, change, or ..." settings.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 when I'd installed MySQL Workbench via Ubuntu Software app (snap).

I'd already changed the permissions setting as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334800/470749, but it didn't help.

The solution for me was to uninstall MySQL Workbench and then download and install from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ fresh.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone. Currently, I am using ubuntu 20.04, I had the same problem. I fixed it by uninstalling the snap store version and installing it from the official MySQL website (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) after I installed it, it worked perfectly fine. Here are the installation steps I used. (https://linuxhint.com/installing_mysql_workbench_ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I simply made an ssh connection to the server via the Linux terminal. Then, I tried to connect using MySQLWorkbench again and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

snap version can't access ~/.ssh/known_hosts

1. create new empty file /home/user/snap/mysql-workbench-community/12/.ssh/known_hosts
2. enter this path in Edit - Preferences - SHH - Known hosts filename
3. reboot MySQL Workbench